# mediaCapture windows 8.1 winjs app

Tags: java, html, video, windows-8.1, winjs

I am using mediaCapture to capture video and after that showing the video before uploading it.Iam using video tag to show the video before uploading .my issue is that the video is not showing in full screen. I gave the height and width of the video tag to 100% even then its showing small.Is there any way to solve the issue.

[image]

```js
var videoplayer = document.getElementById("capturedVideo");
videoplayer.src = URL.createObjectURL(storageFile, { oneTimeOnly: true });videoplayer.controls = true;
```

```html
 <video id="capturedVideo" class="capturedVideo" autoplay="autoplay"></video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by setting msZoom propert to true.

eg:videoplayer.msZoom = true;

[documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767398.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Is this on a phone? What happens if you hold the device in landscape mode (tilt it counter-clockwise)? I suspect you're not applying the correct rotation to the preview.

Have a look at the Universal [Camera Starter Kit](http://aka.ms/2015builduniversalcamerasample). It's a Win10 sample, but most of the code there applies to 8/8.1 as well. Specifically, look at the `setPreviewRotationAsync()` method.

Alternatively, you could try locking the orientation to landscape like so:

```
Display.DisplayInformation.autoRotationPreferences = Display.DisplayOrientations.landscape;
```

Although unless you're taking care of manually rotating your UI, it won't make for a good experience.